# Is question about "actual price" off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I just read this question [Raspberry Pi Zero actual price?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38597/raspberry-pi-zero-actual-price).

I was wondering if this site is the right place for this kind of question considering that this will, probably, change quickly and a search on internet give easily a more accurate answer.

What is your opinion ?

Comment: I don't think so, the price changes, it might be a different price in your currency, and it's really strait forward to search google for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

While I think that this particular question is indeed not really helpful, many technical questions and the solutions we provide as answers out-date also quite fast. So the ephemerality of information should not be an argument for off-topicness.

Comment: The question make me think it was like asking "What is the actual time", but maybe you're right an the technical questions are also valid for a couple of months...

Answer (score 2):

If you want an opinion, I didn't like that question when I first saw it, but it is a bit of a grey area. My dilemma w/ closing questions is I can't just cast one vote of 5, so I prefer to withhold it except in cases that seem really egregious, and beyond that let other members of the community decide.  Particularly so if no one has cast any close votes, and the question itself has a lot of upvotes, as this one does.

To give the question credit, the Raspberry Pi is why where here and so when a new product is released there are bound to be straightforward questions related to that.  If our focus were a particular piece of software, there are analogous questions related to versions and distribution that would be considered firmly on topic.

Finally, that facts can be ephemeral doesn't not make them facts.  The material here is clearly timestamped.  Like a lot of places we do have a lot of outdated material.  Although it doesn't apply to this question very well, if you notice that and have a few minutes to point it out, leave a comment or better yet, submit an edit.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to look at the pi zero and not consider the advertised price as the major feature (a few will benefit from the size, but most of the discussion seems to be about the resulting limitation, rather than what the size might enable).

If that price isn't a reality for people in some markets, then in effect the board isn't a reality either.

One could argue that price issues will be transitory; but then so may well be the position of that particular board relative to its potential alternatives.  In particular, it is hard to note the time proximity of the pi zero's announcement to the impending release of another ultra-low-price Embedded Linux board and not wonder if there is some market/attention jostling going on.  It's also quite likely that none of the current offerings from any of the vendors (pi or otherwise) will turn out to be quite what they could have been (still, with the SD card, still, with the blobs, still using a chip you can't realistically buy), a situation which will hopeful improve with time either within product lines or across them.

Normally, SE sites try to steer clear of things like pricing of specific products, however with the concept of this site being (for better or worse) tied to a specific product line, that is much less avoidable than it would be on a site covering a concept which has multiple competing implementations.